# About elements disposition in header: logo + slogan + social

Tags: css

I have this code:

```
<div style="float: left">
  <div style="width: 150px; background-color: red">logo</div>
  <h1 style="width: 250px; background-color: green" >long slogan</h1>
</div>
<div>fb like and g+ buttons</div>
```

Is there any way to place foobar3 above the green div???

NOTE: I want to use this code order (logo > long slogan > social), because I want to show the slogan below the logo in mobiles and tablets, that is my target, so maybe you can tell me any other work around.

Comment: What's foobar3? And what about just using something like `h1:before { content: "foobar3"; }` with a bit of positioning?

Comment: You need to be more specific! What you want to do or what programmign languages you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want that order logo > long slogan > social, then here is code

```
<div style="float: left">
  <div style="width: 150px; background-color: red">logo</div>
  <h1 style="width: 250px; background-color: green" >long slogan</h1>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div>fb like and g+ buttons</div>
```

Comment: @Thanks, your code is perfect for the mobile version of my site, but the monitor version I want to place the "facebook like" above the "n" in slogan.

Comment: Let me get right this all your idea. You want 2 different versions? 1 html version for mobile and second version for monitor?

Comment: Then you should to use user agents, to get which device uses user, and then display right html part or order.

Comment: But Im interested in the responsiveness related to the size of the browser, not to the type of the browser. I think user agents are related to the type of the browser, don't you?

Comment: If you want to make responsive size, then you need to work on % not on px, I think so.